# How to save my online game progress in case of corruption (Poki.com)

Tags: google-chrome, gaming, cache

I had originally asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/397605/how-to-save-my-online-game-progress-in-case-of-corruption-poki-com) in Arqade and the folks there suggested I ask this here in SuperUser.

I play a few online games on poki.com, and all my progress data (like guns, upgrades, etc) are stored in my Chrome cache.

My question is simple: How do I save this cache if I want to switch computers or in the event that my Chrome profile gets screwed up (has happened many times before)? As far as I know syncing with a Google account does not backup your cache, including video game cache.

I've tried looking through the forums and other places but I haven't found a working or applicable solution to my unique circumstance.

Comment: Why don't you just backup your Google user profile?

Comment: @Ramhound I tried that twice but it only saved my bookmarks, history, and passwords

Comment: I don't understand how that is possible.  I routinely transfer my Google profiles between different machines.  I can only assume that perhaps your actual progress is not actually stored in the cache.

Comment: @Ramhound My bad, I hadn't looked deep enough. I found my profile with the relevant assets for the website and recreating the profile with the proper content saved my progress. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I tend to avoid these, but NIR is somewhat reputable and I've used several of their applications before without any notable issues, so [here's](https://support.moonpoint.com/network/web/browser/chrome/ChromeCacheView/) a 3rd party freeware they've developed for accessing Chrome cache files.

Aside from that, I'm seeing that there should be an internal page (`chrome://cache/`) for viewing cache files as well, but it seems either my system (CrOS) either doesn't support it, or the page may have been deprecated since.  If it's the latter, I expect you might be able to use `chrome://net-export`, but I've not personally used this feature before so take that with a grain of salt.  There's also Google's [Takeout](https://takeout.google.com) feature, not sure if it works for cache files but it should for anything that's synced OTA.

Another potential option to look at would be DevOps, you should see a tab that opens up with a file navigation window on the left-hand side; underneath `www.poki.com` you should see a folder named `assets` which then has various folders with obfuscated names (presumably the game applications and their loaded scripts).  Be warned: as I am not affiliated with the site nor am I a developer, I make no assertion that saving these files will equate to saving your game progress.  You may want to verify with the site's (or any other) developer.

Lastly, if you're on Windows OS, the last option I can think of would be to locate and directly take a copy of your browser's cache directory.  Note that all of the above methods make the assumption that the site makes use of a local resource to save/load your progress, and that said data is openly accessible and modular.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I was able to go to the Google folder and see all the profiles which contained the relevant assets and was able to back them up.

Comment: No problem!  If my answer was of help to you, I'd appreciate it if you might consider voting it up or selecting it as the answer to this post.  If you have any further questions, you can add-on in comments or create another question thread.

Comment: I did upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation for it to show lol.